# Another {"<XXX xmlns=''> was not expected."} Deserializing Error

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

So I know there's a bunch of questions related to this, and I've perused those, but still can't get my instance of this issue resolved.

The inner exception:

```
{"<CostSchedule xmlns='urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3'> was not expected."}
```

My XML document starts like this:

```
<urn:CostSchedule 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:urn="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3" 
xmlns:urn1="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:8" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3 http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/uncefact/data/standard/CostSchedule_3p0.xsd" 
xmlns="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3">
```

Which I'm trying to deserialize to a class that was defined by xsd.exe using the above documents schema. The class starts like this:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([ElementName]:="CostSchedule", [Namespace]:="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class CostScheduleType
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing here? To me it looks like I have all the necessary serialization tags for the class, but I can't seem to make this work.

Comment: Try serializing an instance of that type and compare that with your input.

Comment: <CostSchedule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CostSchedule:3" /> is the result. When I try to deserialize this, I get the same error, which is even more puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The deserializer required that I explicitly state the type of object I am deserializing.

```
ElementsLocal = New CostScheduleType 
'This was ElementsLocal = New Object before

        Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(ElementsLocal.GetType)
        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(LocalFileURI, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            Using objStreamReader As New XmlTextReader(fs)
                'If ser.CanDeserialize(objStreamReader) Then ElementsLocal = ser.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
                ElementsLocal = ser.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
```

Comment: For completeness, please post the code you were using before to deserialize. Also, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: I have same problem in C# but this answer did not help me with what John said...code is incomplete